# Setting a scope variable from a directive with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've gone through what must be 20 similar questions asked on SO but have yet to find a solution for my situation, so I hope you guys can help me out.

The goal is to sort the list of names by the property that's provided in the "sort-type" attribute of the directive, but only for the list within each controller (not all lists at the same time).

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-controller="TestController as testOne">
   <b>By:</b> {{testOne.sortType}}<br>
   <b>Reverse:</b> {{testOne.sortReverse}}<br>
   <div ng-repeat="item in testOne.list">
       <p table-sort sort-type="name" sort-reverse="false"><a href="#">Sort by name</a></p>
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="childItem in testOne.childList | orderBy:testOne.sortType">{{childItem.name}}</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div ng-controller="TestController as testTwo">
   <b>By:</b> {{testTwo.sortType}}<br>
   <b>Reverse:</b> {{testTwo.sortReverse}}<br>
   <div ng-repeat="item in testTwo.list">
       <p table-sort sort-type="name" sort-reverse="false"><a href="#">Sort by name</a></p>
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="childItem in testTwo.childList | orderBy:testTwo.sortType">{{childItem.name}}</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript (Angular)**

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.sortType    = 'oldOrder';
    vm.sortReverse = false;

    vm.list      = [1];
    vm.childList = [{ name: 'Jimmy' },
                    { name: 'Danny' },
                    { name: 'Bobby' }];
}

/////////////////////////////////////

app.directive('tableSort', tableSort);

function tableSort() {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFunc,
    };

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('click', function() {
            if(scope.sortType === attr.sortType) {
                scope.sortReverse = !scope.sortReverse;
            } else {
                scope.sortType = attr.sortType;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/L0o8a1m2/)**

My actual application is a bit more complex but I've tried to abstract it as much as possible.

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Several things going on here:

1. you are using the controllerAs syntax on your templates but
   you are changing scope variables in your directive. hence your
   controller variables are never changed.
2. your directive is inside of the `ng-repeat` which means that
       you are actuating actually on a child scope so if you are setting
       variables directive on the scope your `ng-repeat` won't be able to
       reach them because they are being set after the child scope are
       created.
3. you are using element.on which executes outside of angular
       digest which means you would have to call scope.$apply to let
       angular know that something happened.

Take a look at this 
https://jsfiddle.net/rez8ey12/

i hope it helps

Comment: This works pretty well for me. Thanks for taking the time to help out!